# Как вшить звук в exe c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Написал прогу которая воспроизводит звуки при нажатии клавиши, но что бы она работала нужно таскать музыкальные файлы вместе с ней. Как добавить звук непосредственно в exe?

Comment: Засуньте их в ресурсы.

Comment: просто в папку с ресурсами их закинуть или что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создай файл ресурсов (`.rc`) и внутри определи все звуки, которые ты используешь.

Пример: я хочу воспроизвести звук из файла `back.wav` для этого я в проекте добавил файл `sound.rc` (название произвольное) и отредактировал его в текстовом редакторе, написав `backsound WAVE back.wav` (справа текущее название файла со звуком, слева то, как ты будешь указывать его в проекте)

В итоге проект у меня выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где `back.wav` - мелодия
`asd.rc` - файл, содержащий строку `backsound WAVE back.wav`
`Source.cpp` - сам исполняемый код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

#pragma comment (lib , "winmm.lib")

int main(void)
{
    printf("Playback in progress.\nPress any key to exit...");
    PlaySoundA((LPCSTR)"backsound", NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_ASYNC);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

По итогу, при сборке и запуске исполняемого файла звук спокойно воспроизводится.

Я не отрицаю, что вероятно мой метод - костыль т.к. я занимался этим первый раз и изучил все, что нашел в кратчайшие сроки, однако он функционирует и надеюсь поможет.
Сайты, которые я использовал для изучения: [1](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2787049.html), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=msvc-160), [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565439/how-to-playsound-in-c-using-windows-api), [5](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=msvc-160)